# How to output a list of numbers from a file on the same line in java

Tags: java, bluej

What I have so far:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FileEg
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
  { int sum = 0, ctr = 0;
    double next;
    String line;
    String filename = "eg.txt";
    StringTokenizer st;
    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("eg.out");
    outFile.println("Output File");
    try
    { Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader (filename));
      while (inFile.hasNext())
      { line = inFile.nextLine();
        st = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (st.hasMoreTokens())
        { next = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
          sum += next;
          ctr++;
          outFile.println(next);          
        }
    }     
    outFile.println("number of integers read is " + ctr);
    outFile.println("average is " + sum/(double)ctr);
    outFile.close();
    }     //end of try
   catch(FileNotFoundException e)
   { System.out.println ("The file eg.dat was not found.");
   }
   catch(NumberFormatException e)
   { System.out.println ("sorry - number format error");
     System.out.println(e);
   }
  }
}
```

---

I need to get the output at least 2 different lines and with more than on number on one line. so far it comes out like this in the output file.

Output File

2.5

6.2

9.3

1.2

3.5

6.1

5.0

8.0

4.0

8.0

number of integers read is 10
average is 5.2

Comment: Use `print()` instead of `println()`?

Comment: @JB Nizet

but I need more then just one line after that. plus then "number of integers read is 10..." is on the same line as the numbers. It needs to be like above but at least 1 line with more then one number.

Comment: @JB Nizet

or at least 2 lines

Comment: I don't understand anything. Provide an example input and output, and describe what the problem is in a clearer way. But you probably just need a combination of print and println.

Comment: create a program that reads a input file that contains at least 10 numbers - 4 integers and at least 6 real numbers. Then in the output file have the program print the numbers out on at least 2 different lines and with more than one number on each line. Then at the end have the program print out the number of integers and their average.

Comment: You know that you'll get at least 10 numbers. So, print (for example) the 5 first numbers on a single line, then use println to start a new line, then print all the other ones on the same line. You just need a counter whichis incremented at each iteration and an if test inside the loop.

Comment: So an if loop in side the while (st.hasMoreTokens())? can I use the ctr: counter variable I already have or do I need a whole new counter?

Answer (score 0):

Excuse the answer listing as i can't post comments yet. But What I think JB Nizet is trying to get you to do is something like this (I havn't tested this mind you, but it should be close):

```
int numbCounter = 0;  
while (inFile.hasNext())     
  { line = inFile.nextLine();
    st = new StringTokenizer(line);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    { next = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());
      sum += next;
      ctr++;
      if (numbCounter <5){
      outFile.print(next + " ");
      }
      else if(numbCounter == 5){
          outFile.println();
          outFile.print(next + " ");
      }
      else {
          outFile.print(next + " ");
      }

      numbCounter++;
    }
  }
```